# Duda sobre exception c#

Tags: c#

¿Porque cuando tengo los tres errores solo me tira el primero, el de día y no tira el de mes y año?

```
if (di > 0 && di <= 31)
{
    dia = di;
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("\n"+ "El día no puede ser menor que 1 ni mayor que 31");
}
if (me > 0 && me <= 12)
{
    mes = me;
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("\n" + "El mes no puede ser menor que 1 ni mayor que 12");
}
if (an < 1992)
{
    anio = an;
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("\n" + "Debe ser mayor a 25 años para poder registrarse");
}
```

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo, cuando se tira una Exception, se para el flujo de ejecucion del programa, asi que, literalmente, tu programa para y los otros if no se ejecutan.

Comment: eso sería mejor implementado con bloques _else if_ .

Answer (score 3):

El uso del comando `throw new Exception` detiene la ejecución del código, prácticamente las lineas posteriores son omitidas ya que se cumplió la condición en donde declaraste la **exception**.

Si lo que deseas es mostrar todos los mensajes posibles al usuario, podrías replantear la lógica de validaciones aplicando lo siguiente:

```
string msg = "";

if (di > 0 && di <= 31){
    dia = di;
}else{
    msg = msg + "\n El día no puede ser menor que 1 ni mayor que 31";
}

if (me > 0 && me <= 12){
    mes = me;
}else{
    msg = msg + "\n El mes no puede ser menor que 1 ni mayor que 12";
}

if (an < 1992){
    anio = an;
}else{
    msg = msg + "\n Debe ser mayor a 25 años para poder registrarse";
}

if (msg.Length > 0){
    throw new Exception(msg);
}
```

Almacenar en una variable el texto del posible mensaje hasta evaluar todas las condiciones posibles, al final se lanza la **exception** si existe contenido en la variable `msg`.

Answer (score 1):

Para, literalmente constestar tu pregunta, debes saber que cuando "tiras" una `Exception` se [para la ejecución del programa.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky9bw27e.aspx), es por eso que las demas instrucciones no se ejecutan.

La clase `Exception` y cualquiera de sus clases derivadas consumen muchos recursos y memoria y deberias tener cuidado de usarlas, salvo en los casos en que en verdad se requiere y [seguir estos consejos para hacerlo.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx#Errors)

P.D. [Blasito](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90175/duda-sobre-exception-c/90182#90182) te ha dado un buen ejemplo de como evitar usar en exceso `Exception`

Answer (score 0):

`throw new Exception` interrumpe la ejecuccion de tu programa por lo que ya no continua con el proceso.

El principal objetivo de utilizar Exception es controlar los errores ajenos a nuestro codigo, cosas que no estan a nuestro alcance para controlar (ejemplo desconexion, error en disco,dll, etc).

Habria que replantear tu codigo basicamente es una validación el cual puedes manejar y regresar como una coleccion o mensajes de cadena ya se te ha planteado en otras respuestas.

Ejemplo:

```
//el indice lo puedes definir en este caso se definio como error1, errror2
Dictionary<string, string> errores = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string msg = "";

if (di > 0 && di <= 31){
    dia = di;
}else{
    errores.Add("erro1","El día no puede ser menor que 1 ni mayor que 31");    
}

if (me > 0 && me <= 12){
    mes = me;
}else{
    errores.Add("erro2","El mes no puede ser menor que 1 ni mayor que 12");    
}

if (an < 1992){
    anio = an;
}else{   
    errores.Add("erro3","Debe ser mayor a 25 años para poder registrarse");
}
```